# copy from one table to another with the same column count and name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following two tables...

```
Table1
colA    colB    colC    
1       a       w    
2       b       w    
3       c       s        
4       b       g    
5       n         


Table2
colA    colB    colC    
1       w       f    
2       w       r    
3       s       g
```

I want to copy from table1 to table2 using UPDATE query, the problem I have is I have to SET all column name in which I have 100 column for each table, But I have the same column count and name too.

what would be easy way to run query UPDATE in php?

is there some foreach thing out there might be...

Here is what I have now...

```
public function update($id){
            try {
                UPDATE table1 b 
                INNER JOIN connect c 
                ON c.ID = b.ID 
                INNER JOIN table2 a 
                ON a.ID_a = c.ID_a 
                SET b.colA = a.colA,
                b.colB = a.colB,
                b.colC = a.colC
                .
                .
                .
                .
                . coontinue here all column name..
                .
                .
                WHERE a.ID_a = '".$id."' ";
             } catch(PDOException $e) {
                 $e->getMessage();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

some idea please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a table with 100 columns is not normalized.

Comment: it is really, that how the structure is...

Comment: That might be 'how it is', but that doesn't necessarily mean it's normalized! What kind of stuff do you have in there?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do it via `UPDATE` syntax. You can use `INSERT..SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT * FROM `table1`
```

this will works if you have exactly same structure in both tables. If not, you have to write column names (and map columns from first table to the second).

If you wand to *replace* corresponding values, then you should first delete present values:

```
DELETE FROM `table2` WHERE `colA` IN (SELECT `colA` FROM `table1`)
```

Comment: That will create new rows instead of updating data from one table in the other.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it that OP wants? (upd. edited post to achieve replace issue)

Comment: Yep. As long as you delete first.

Comment: how do I use with your INSERT statement, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...?

Comment: No, if you'll `DELETE` items first, your key values will not be duplicated

Comment: @MR.Test Note that if you use this you will be prone if you add more columns or change column positions.... don't know the reason why it's not normalized?

Comment: what about the INNE JOIN issues?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to update data in first table use values in other table you can use next statement

```
UPDATE table_name AS t1 
SET t1.field_name = (SELECT field_name FROM other_table AS t2 WHERE t1.field=t2.field)
```